# PHP Missing Argument 3 for build_calendar()

Tags: php, calendar

I'm building a simple calendar and I'm encountering a missing argument error with following code snippet:

```
function build_calendar($month,$year,$dateArray) {//line 3
//rest of code
}
```

**Error**

> Warning: Missing argument 3 for build_calendar() on line 3

Comment: Usually this kind of warning is a bit longer like: PHP Warning:  Missing argument 3 for x(), called in fun.php on line 7 and defined in fun.php on line 3... just to confirm, you pasted the whole warning message?

Comment: You need to show how you are calling this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
function build_calendar($month,$year,$dateArray = null) {//line 3
//rest of code
}
```